# Docker flask app working on Mac but not Windows OS

Tags: python, windows, docker, flask, operating-system

I built a docker app that works across multiple Mac machines. However, when it is run on Windows 10 (with the most up to date Docker installed), the following error is produced when going to http://0.0.0.0:5000/

```
This site can’t be reached
The webpage at http://0.0.0.0:5000/ might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.
ERR_ADDRESS_INVALID
```

For reference, the file `flaskapp.py` ends with:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host= '0.0.0.0')
```

The Dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM python:3
WORKDIR /app
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . /app
EXPOSE 5000
CMD [ "python", "flaskapp.py" ]
```

The docker was built and pushed to docker hub, then pulled and run with the command:

`docker run -p 5000:5000 username/reponame`

When run on multiple Mac machines, the terminal prints out:

```
 * Running on http://0.0.0.0:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

and I can navigate to the browser with this address and my app works.

On windows, it prints the same thing in the command line, but the site cannot be reached.

Any ideas? I thought docker was supposed to work across platform.

Comment: 0.0.0.0 is a special IPv4 address that means "everywhere"; it makes sense to use it as a listening address (in your `app.run()` call) but not as an outbound URL.  What kind of Docker are you using on Windows (the Desktop application or the older Toolbox setup)?

Comment: Desktop application

Comment: Does `http://localhost:5000/` work?  (It should work, whenever the browser/client is on the same host as the container, and you're not on Docker Toolbox or calling from inside another container.)

Comment: Ok, will try. So run the docker with the same command `docker run -p 5000:5000 username/reponame`, but then use `http://localhost:5000/` instead of what it prints in the terminal? Also, does docker toolbox behave differently?

Comment: For Docker Toolbox you need the VM's IP address, usually 192.168.99.100, but whatever `docker-machine ip` tells you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not the way to do it. You have to use host's or container's IP addresses.
For starters try to type in your browser:

1. http://localhost:5000
2. http://127.0.0.1:5000

You can also try to run in Windows command line:
ipconfig

This should give you a list of IP addresses that your Windows host has,
then you can try access your app using those addresses.